# Make relative values per Group in a pd DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider this DataFrame given with many colums, but it has a feature defined in the column `'feature'` and some values in the column `'values'`.

I want in an extra column the relative values per feature (group) The desired result is manually precalculated by me in the column `'desired'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'feature': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        'values': [30.0, 20.0, 25.0, 100.0, 250.0, 50.0],
        'desired': [0.6, 0.4, 1.0, 0.25, 0.625, 0.125],
        'more_columns': range(6),
    },
)
```

Which leads to the DataFrame

```
   feature  values  desired  more_columns
0        1    30.0    0.600             0
1        1    20.0    0.400             1
2        2    25.0    1.000             2
3        3   100.0    0.250             3
4        3   250.0    0.625             4
5        3    50.0    0.125             5
```

So for the group defined by feature `1` the desired values are 0.6 and 0.4 (because `0.6 = 30 / (20+30)`) and so on.

I came to these values manually using

```
for feature, group in df.groupby('feature'):
    rel_values = (group['values'] / group['values'].sum()).values
    df[df['feature'] == feature]['result'] = rel_values  # no effect
    print(f'{feature}: {rel_values}')

# which prints:
1: [0.6 0.4]
2: [1.]
3: [0.25  0.625 0.125]

# but df remains unchanged
```

I believe that there must be a smart and fast way in pandas to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with `sum`ed values with same size as original `df`, so possible divide by `div`:

```
df['new'] = df['values'].div(df.groupby('feature')['values'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
   feature  values  desired  more_columns    new
0        1    30.0    0.600             0  0.600
1        1    20.0    0.400             1  0.400
2        2    25.0    1.000             2  1.000
3        3   100.0    0.250             3  0.250
4        3   250.0    0.625             4  0.625
5        3    50.0    0.125             5  0.125
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('feature')['values'].transform('sum'))
0     50.0
1     50.0
2     25.0
3    400.0
4    400.0
5    400.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

**Performance:**

In real data depends by number of groups and length of `DataFrame`.

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = np.random.randint(1000,size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'values':np.random.rand(N)})
#print (df)

In [272]: %timeit df['new'] = df['values'].div(df.groupby('feature')['values'].transform('sum'))
80.7 ms ± 2.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [273]: %timeit df['desired'] = df.groupby('feature').apply(lambda g: g['values'] / g['values'].sum()).values
1.17 s ± 23.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [274]: %timeit df['desired'] = df.groupby('feature')['values'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
727 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1** : Using [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)

```
df['desired'] = df.groupby('feature')['values'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

**Method 2** : Use `apply`

```
df['desired'] = df.groupby('feature').apply(lambda g: g['values'] / g['values'].sum()).values
```

Output:

```
    feature  values  desired  more_columns
0        1    30.0    0.600             0
1        1    20.0    0.400             1
2        2    25.0    1.000             2
3        3   100.0    0.250             3
4        3   250.0    0.625             4
5        3    50.0    0.125             5
```

Comment: I have to test it, but I guess it should be slowier as `transform` solution.

Comment: It is my understanding that `apply` tends to be slower than `transform`. Hence my method 1 is `transform`.

Comment: It is a bit better, but still slow, check timings in my answer.

Comment: I think `lambda` makes my `transform` slower. Already +1 ed to your answer. @jezrael

Comment: Reason why it is slowier is you divide for each group, why my solution divide all column at once.

Comment: I see. Good to know. Thanks @jezrael